# Vim Plugin Path Issue

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-ctrlp, plugin-vim-plug

I'm trying to get Vim all decked out with some fancy plugins on my work laptop but I am running into some issues.

Using `echo &rtp` I can see that Vim will look in several directories for startup files, including the `H:` drive.

My problem is that `H:` is a network drive at work and I don't want to have anything Vim related in that drive. Additionally I disconnect from the network at times so it would be a problem.

I installed CtrlP and it is only indexing this `H` drive which has nothing in it so obviously it is not providing any benefit. All of my code is under a directory off `C:`.

When I launch NERDTRee it displays `NERD_tree_1 - (H:\)`. In order to get other plugins to work I hardcoded the path (I use vim-plug):

```
call plug#begin('C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vimfiles/.vim/plugged)
```

I'm probably missing something obvious right in front of my face. I do have other plugins installed and they are working. My environment:
Windows 7
gVim 8

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that you don't know how "H:" is getting added to your runtime path and you'd like to get it out of there?

Comment: Note there is a typo in the `call plug#begin` line (missing closing `'`). Is this also in your vimrc, or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes that was a copy paste error, my bad. @Jsoh Petrie, yes I'd like to get that H the h out of there.